# How to update live NSSlider value?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

I have slider with volume value. I need changed volume in live. Whats wrong in my code?

```
@IBOutlet weak var volumeSliderCurr: NSSlider!

@IBAction func volumeSlider(sender: AnyObject) {
    var event: NSEvent = NSApplication.sharedApplication().currentEvent!
    mouseUp(event)
}

override func mouseUp(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseUp(theEvent)
    audioPlayer.volume = volumeSliderCurr.floatValue
    currVolume = volumeSliderCurr.floatValue
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you set `Continuous` in the properties of Interface Builder you get permanent updates of the slider value:

[image]

Comment: What's the programatic way to do this?

Comment: I have no idea. Just ask a new question. Ehrm. Do you mean to set it in XCode programmatically or how to do that in usage of  the GUI?

Comment: The according property of NSSlider is `isContinuous`.